# Checking bags through on separate OneWorld bookings?

Tags: luggage, international-travel, oneworld, royal-jordanian

In a little over a week I am flying from TLV to ORD on Royal Jordanian Airlines, but have a separate booking to fly from ORD to ABQ (ALbuquerque, NM).

I have a layover of four hours and twenty minutes in ORD, but I worry that if I encounter delay, getting my bags and having to re-check them would be a pain (I do know that I will have to get my bag and go through customs, but this takes much less time).

These two airlines are OneWorld partners, so I was wondering if they would be willing to check my bag all the way through or not?  I have seen that some airlines in the OneWorld agreement do this, and others do not, but I have not seen anything about Royal Jordanian Airlines yet.

Does anyone have any specific experiences that could help me with my situation?

Comment: Is ORD to ABQ on American?  You didn't specify the airline.

Comment: Given that you'll have to queue up to redrop your baggage after customs, there's probably only an extra 2-3 minutes to get the onward baggage tags issued then

Comment: Yes, ORD to ABQ is on American - sorry.

Answer (score 2):

While in general there are airline agreements that would allow you to check your bags through to the final destination, none of these applies when you are flying into the USA and then connecting onto an internal flight.  The American law stipulates that you must claim your bags in your first point of landing in the USA and then re-check them on the internal flight.  This applies regardless of whether you're flying different airlines or the same one.

Some years ago I was flying from Mexico to Washington DC with a transfer in Charlotte NC.  The flight was all one itinerary with the same carrier - and yet, I still had to claim my bags in Charlotte and re-check them in again.  As a result, I missed the connection to Washington.  Luckily, the airline had another flight to IAD only two hours later, so they put me on that flight.

With your layover time, you should be fine, however if delays do occur, then there is a risk of you not making the connection.  I wouldn't dwell on it too much though - you will still make it to your destination.  I suggest you notify the airline for your internal flight about your connection so that they could put a corresponding remark on your reservation.

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate this is, if only because I've flown on a single itinerary before to the U.S., and while I did have to pick up my bag to go through customs, after customs all I did was hand my luggage to a baggage handler just after customs, who put it on a conveyor belt.  I didn't really have to "re-check" it, because it already had the tags to be checked all the way through.

Comment: @Jacob a couple of times I had to do it, I had to get my bags, get them through the x-ray conveyor and then take them to the desks for the specific airline I was flying with - who put them onto the conveyor belt, because the tags were already there.